# How to send the correct request to my rails-api thanks to ng-resource?

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, rails-api, ngresource

I created an API using the rails-api gem and I have an client app based on angular in which I use ng-resource.

I do think that the request I send to my API should be more like {post=>{"kind"=>"GGG"}} and not {"kind"=>"GGG"} of I have to find a way for my api to work with the request I send now. For now I'm stuck with 400 Bad Request errors and I can't find out how to fix it.

- Here is my rails controller :

  ```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    # GET /posts
    # GET /posts.json
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:update, :create]

    def index
      @posts = Post.all

      render json: @posts
    end

    # GET /posts/1
    # GET /posts/1.json
    def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

      render json: @post
    end

    # POST /posts
    # POST /posts.json
    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      if @post.save
        render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
      else
        render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
    # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
    def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

      if @post.update(params[:post])
        head :no_content
      else
        render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    # DELETE /posts/1
    # DELETE /posts/1.json
    def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy

      head :no_content
    end

    private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:post, :kind)
    end
  end
  ```
- Here is my angular controller :

  ```
       $scope.postData = {};
       $scope.newPost = function() {
        console.log($scope.postData);
            var post = new Post($scope.postData);
            post.$save($scope.postData);
        }
  ```
- Here is my angular factory :

  ```
     .factory('Post', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:3000/posts');
     })
  ```
- In my logs I have :

  ```
   Started POST "/posts?kind=GGG" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-26 18:21:21 +0200
   Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
     Parameters: {"kind"=>"GGG"}
   Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

   ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: post):
     app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:55:in `post_params'
     app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:23:in `create'
  ```

-

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution or any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:post, :kind)
end
```

To be:

```
def post_params
  params.permit(:post, :kind)
end
```

And you problem will be fixed.